# Loading an object with Three.js fails (missing formal parameter)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use Three.js (OGL + JavaScript) to load an object from file. I have an working example without loading it (some basic elements rendered). But when I try to load object using `JSONLoader.load(...)`, Firefox console shows error:

```
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter
```

The reference: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader

The source code for my added fragment (loading object), which cause an error:

```
//loading an object
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(); //works so far
loader.load("./Project2/proj/grzyb.js", 
    function(geometry, 
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture, ambient: 0xbbbbbb } )
        //for the line above, in Firefox console i get 
        //"SyntaxError: missing formal parameter"
    ){
        var materials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(
            new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture, ambient: 0xbbbbbb } )
        );
        grzyb = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
        grzyb.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
        grzyb.position.set(2,2,2);
        grzyb.receiveShadow = true;
        grzyb.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(grzyb);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert MeshLambertMaterial creation into a function header definition. Function header can only contain parameter names - not any actual code to create them.

Also it is not clear whether you want to use material coming from model file or your own material with texture that you loaded elsewhere (in the example there is no code that would set texture variable). Assuming you want to use materials from model, your code should look like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(); //works so far
loader.load("./Project2/proj/grzyb.js", 
function(geometry, materials) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    grzyb = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    grzyb.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
    grzyb.position.set(2,2,2);
    grzyb.receiveShadow = true;
    grzyb.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(grzyb);
    }
```

);

if you want to use different material, then set material variable to anything you want. exmaple:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.LoadTexture( "../path/image.jpg" );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:texture } );
var grzyb = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```